# mysql_error() doesn't return false but mysql_fetch_assoc($result) asks for resource instead of boolean

Tags: php, mysql

mysql_error() is returning blank but the while throws an error asking for a resource instead of a boolean. What could be the reason?

```
 $query2 = "SELECT song FROM songs where id like '$lastComparison[$sg]'";

         $results = mysql_query($query2,$link2);

error_log(mysql_error());

          while ($rows2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
                $lastComparison[$sg] = $rows2['song_title'];
                }
```

Comment: Your query went fine but it simply didn't find any result to display, most likely ? mysql_fetch_assoc returns false when your $results is empty.

Comment: `if (!$results) {
    die('Ungültige Anfrage: ' . mysql_error());
}` maybe this helps

Comment: `"Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows."` - [`mysql_fetch_assoc() Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: The question is NOT about what `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions. You should NOT write new code with them. I suggest you rewrite your code with `mysqli_*` or PDO and ask again if you have still problems with it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This is part of a lareg codebase which is all written with the previous standard. The new syntax will be implemented later.